# Wordpress frontpage adds a url parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I had installed a wordpress plugin with malicious code. After i have clean it i have notice, although i dont know if that plugin was the caution of the "problem", that when i type my site domain for homepage `www.ttesting.com` it will redirect me to the url `www.ttesting.com/?v=342543354`, homepage shows correctly .Where should i start looking for so i can  remove that get url parameter ?

i want when i press `www.ttesting.com` on broswer to stay as it is and not get some url query parameters.

PS: on settings -> general   both website and display url are www.ttesting.com
its a nginx web server

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the URL displayed when you go to settings -> general settings in your WP-admin?

Comment: hello the urls in settings -> general are plain ( www.ttesting.com )

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess file?

Comment: Hello Daniel thanks for the response!
I use nginx web service so i dont have a .htaccess file
on site-available there isn't such a redirection

Comment: You should look at the HTML generated by the browser. There may be a script still being executed somehow

Comment: Thanks Daniel spot the parameter, it was woocommerce option
Default Customer Location : geolocation(with cache support) . I changed it and the url is now "normal"

Comment: Oh my goodness! To think it seemed like malicious code of some sort! I would suggest you answer your own question to help anyone else who may have this issue in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel spot the parameter in html, it was woocommerce option Default Customer Location : geolocation(with cache support) . I changed it and the url is now "normal"

So in order to remove ?v=4325443543 get query parameter you have to change Default Customer Location